# Is it possible to make a circular GUI in java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm just wondering, is it possible in JAVA to make a circular GUI with components inside it (buttons, text fields ... etc) ?

Comment: As an aside, shaped windows are a waste of valuable screen acreage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely possible, albeit in a manner of speaking - they're not truly circular, however they have some "transparent" parts, which are filled in with a screen capture prior to displaying the frame, etc.

A good introduction to performing this can be seen in the online chapter 6.5 of [Killer Game Programming in Java](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/ch045/index.html).

HTH

Answer (score 3):

These will give you lots of help.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/02/27/translucent-and-shaped-windows-in-core-java.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is very much possible, has been made available since build 12 of JDK 6.0u10. Have a read of these.

http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/02/27/translucent-and-shaped-windows-in-core-java.html

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/